# Moment.js issues with .format() using Zulu time

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp, momentjs, utc

I am working on a script that needs to retrieve and store a timestamp from a database. The timestamp from the database is retrieved as a UTC Zulu formatted string "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ". I want to store this timestamp in the format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS" in local time. I am currently attempting to do this with moment.js, I have had little success with ".toISOString()" and other methods.

However, I have noticed that the output from "moment(timestamp).format()" does not return the string I am expecting from what I understand so far about UTC. Here is a code example that replicates my issue:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var timestamp = new Date('2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z');

console.log(timestamp);
console.log(moment(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss'));
console.log(moment(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS'));
```

This is my output:

```
2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z
2018-05-30T16:01:01.011
2018-05-30T16:05:11.111
```

This is my expected out:

```
2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z
2018-05-30T16:01:01.111
2018-05-30T16:01:01.111
```

Why does the change in case from 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss' to 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS' in .format() cause a different output? Is my expected output correct or have a misunderstood moment.(timestamp).format()? Lastly, is there a better way to achieve my expected output given the circumstances?

Comment: `mm` is minutes `MM` is months

Comment: How about reading the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)? 1. There's no `sss` format, 2. The uppercase version `S`, `SS`, ... returns fractional seconds, hence milliseconds, ..., 3. `MM` returns the month

Comment: Be careful `new Date()` will change your timestamp to your local timestamp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

MM is months thats why you got `2018-05-30T16:05:11.111` a 5

there is no `sss` but there is a `SSS`

you said you want in this format "YYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS" I assume MM you mean minutes due to your expected outcome. This is an odd way to store a date as there are no months and it's repeating seconds.

I'd suggest storing in UTC.

```js
var timestamp = new Date('2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z');

console.log(timestamp);
console.log(moment(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSS'));

// i'd suggest UTC over formating but if you were i'd use
console.log(moment(timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:mm:SSS'));
//2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z
//2018-05-30T16:01:01.111
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Please let me know if this how you want it.

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is what I needed. I had not spotted that MM represented months, and mm represented minutes. I would like to store my timestamp in UTC unformatted however the npm package odbc that I am using seems to have issues when I query a database with a UTC timestamp. I have needed to format the stamp to get around this issue. Thank for your time Joe!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  whats the issue you're having about querying i'd try solve that instead of this if possible :) have a nice day

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful. It seems to be that the npm package odbc I am using returns my timestamps in the format "2018-05-30T15:35:57.000Z" as an example. I do not know if this is node odbc or the sybase odbc driver on my server causing this. Ironically, though I receive timestamps in this format, if I query the database with them in this format it returns an error. Equally query the databse with this timestamp in UTC returns values from an hour behind local, as if it is not being converted correctly. It has left me with this current method, though not perfect, working with your help =)

Comment: I'd imagine if they're an hour before its because the servers timezone is differenent and the offset will sort but i may be wrong

Comment: How do I get a Zulu timestamp format like 2018-05-30T15:01:01.111Z - console.log(moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:mm:ss.SSSZ'));//returns 2018-05-30T15:01:01.111+00:00

Comment: Z at the end is short for Zulu and means UTC.

Comment: @Vijay - Try .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]'). [] are the Escaping characters and Z will be appended as is after formatting.